# OSGi service vs bundle startup sequence

Tags: osgi

Given two OSGi bundles `foo` and `bar`, and:

- `bar` imports (`Import-Package:`) packages from `foo`.
- `bar` implements a service which is defined in `foo`.

Is it *allowed* that a **service** in `foo` uses (`@Reference`) the service from `bar` (according to OSGi specification)?

It should be technically possible by first resolving the bundles and then starting the services in an order which meets their dependencies.

(I'm less interested whether some specific OSGi implementation supports it.)

**EDIT** Background: This way, an OSGi bundle could provide custom service implementations for some library ([SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Reference` is an SCR annotation for service component runtime specification.
You have to distinguish *resolution* phase (process between installing a bundle and making it *active*) and service references wiring.

Sticking to SCR components - you can imagine two components, both exporting (`@Service` annotation) some service and referencing each other (using `@Reference`) - this way you head into deadlock situation.

But the scenario you described seems fine.

1. `bar` imports packages from `foo` - so it's resolved after foo. Of course if you install bundles manually and you first install `bar` and then `foo`, you have to refresh/restart `bar`
2. `foo` `@Reference`s services from `bar` - it only means that SCR runtime will activate given SCR component in `foo` after the service is available

Karaf using its *features* adds another layer of resolution (standard OSGi resolver) for bundles of the features. So it's always better than installing bundles manually (or dropping them all to some auto-deploy directory).

Also remember one thing. If somehow, your bundle gets `Import-Service` (or `Require-Capability`) manifest header (these may be generated by maven-bundle-plugin), resolution may fail, because services are usually registered asynchronously later, after starting the bundle (using blueprint or scr runtimes). I personally usually get rid of these headers using this configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <_removeheaders>Import-Service,Require-Capability</_removeheaders>
...
    </instructions>
...
```